# Highcharts Heatmap, using pointStart / pointInterval produces a "stairs" effect

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to produce a heatmap using data in the form of an array of 2-values arrays.

According to the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series%3Cheatmap%3E.data) I should be able to chart this data in conjunction with **pointStart** and **pointInterval**:

> For the heatmap series type, points can be given in the following ways:
>
> 1. An array of arrays with 3 or 2 values. In this case, the values correspond to x,y,value. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is inferred. **The x value can also be omitted, in which case the inner arrays should be of length 2. Then the x value is automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and incremented by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the series options.**

I'm trying to chart hourly values, so the data I'm using is in the form:

```
[ [0,0.0022],...,[23,0.012],[0,0.0022],... ]
```

with the first value being the hour and the second one a measurement.

I'm configuring my serie like this:

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1),
pointInterval: 36e5,
colsize: 24 * 36e5,
```

I'm probably interpreting in some wrong way the meaning of *pointInterval* and *colSize* however even after trying several combinations I can't get the chart right.

The chart I get has this strange "stairs" effect:
[image]

Here you can see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nb5vw5sL/

It is based on the "large heatmap" example, I'm simply changing the way data is provided.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interval is added to each point, so your points look this [start, 0,...], [start + interval, 1, ...], [start + 2 * interval, 2, ...] - they create stairs. If you wanto fill the whole heatmap you need to add x value to the point, e.g. like this http://jsfiddle.net/nb5vw5sL/2/

Comment: I see, the documentation is a bit unclear about this. Thanks for the help I will go for the solution you propose.

Comment: UPDATE: I slightly modified your fiddle to reflect my use case to work on the *day*:  http://jsfiddle.net/nb5vw5sL/3/ 
Also your solution certainly solves my problem but doesn't really clarify how pointStart/pointInterval work, still a bit of mistery :\ But thanks again!